# Why doesn't this shell script work?

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a simple script which will resize images. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"

#copy image and resize it
OUTPUT_IMG="newimg.png"
PATH="${PWD}/${OUTPUT_IMG}"

cp "$1" ${OUTPUT_IMG}
mogrify -resize 400x300 ${PATH}
```

I am calling script with 1 parameter (image to be resized)

```
script thisImage.png
```

But I get error `cp command not found` and `mogrify command not found`.

All this works without a script meaning that I have installed all these apps.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `PATH` has a predefined meaning: it's the [search path for programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29). When you type a command name, the shell (or any other program that you tell to execute this command) looks for an executable file in one of the directories mentioned in the `PATH` variable. In your script, `cp` is searched in a subdirectory called `newimg.png` of the current directory (which doesn't even exist, let alone contain an executable file called `cp`.

Use a different variable name in your script. By convention, environment variables that have a meaning to programs are usually in all uppercase. For variables that are local to a script, you can use lowercase letters to avoid clashes (variable names are case-insensitive). Better, use a more significant name (because having variables that only differ in case is confusing to humans).

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"

#copy image and resize it
output_image_name="newimg.png"
output_image_path="${PWD}/${OUTPUT_IMG}"

cp "$1" "$output_image_name"
mogrify -resize 400x300 "$output_image_path"
```

There's no reason to sometimes use the file name and sometimes the full path here though. Furthermore, instead of copying the file then modifying it in place with `mogrify`, you might as well use `convert` directly — `convert` is the same as `mogrify` except that it writes to a different output file.

```
#!/bin/bash
output_image="newimg.png"
convert -resize 400x300 "$1" "$output_image"
```

Comment: `convert` is native as well? also does it preserve quality? I was using mogrify because I know it preserves the quality as same as I use some GUI tool.

Comment: @ubuntico `convert` is from the same package as `mogrify` and uses exactly the same algorithm. The only difference is where it puts its output (same file vs different file).

Answer (score 1):

`PATH` is a predefined shell variable that holds the search path for commands.  You can see its default value by executing `echo $PATH`.  Since you used it in your script, it over-wrote the search path, and could no longer find any commands that are not fully specified, including `cp` and `mogrify`, thus the two errors.

Use a different variable instead of "PATH".  If you're not sure, you can first try `echo $YOUR_VARIABLE` to see if it has a value.